# What is the difference between lerna's run command and yarn's wsrun?

Tags: yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo

[lerna run](https://lernajs.io/) goes through all packages and runs the script you provided the name of. Similarly, [wsrun](https://github.com/hfour/wsrun) seems to be a custom tool that runs the given command "on every individual package, in parallel".

Other than the parallelism feature, why would I choose one over the other?